# Docbook: Chapter number and word "Chapter" in header

Tags: xml, xslt, xsl-fo, docbook

I'm writing documentation in DocBook and want to publish it in PDF with headers and footers. For this purpose I have this style:

```
<xsl:template name="header.content">
    <xsl:param name="pageclass" select="''"/>
    <xsl:param name="sequence" select="''"/>
    <xsl:param name="position" select="''"/>
    <xsl:param name="gentext-key" select="''"/>

  <fo:block>

    <!-- sequence can be odd, even, first, blank -->
    <!-- position can be left, center, right -->
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="$sequence = 'blank'">
        <!-- nothing -->
      </xsl:when>

      <xsl:when test="$position='left'">
        <xsl:call-template name="draft.text"/>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="titleabbrev.markup"/>
        </xsl:when>
    </xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="$position='right'">
       <fo:page-number/>
     </xsl:when>
  </fo:block>
</xsl:template>
```

With this piece of code, I get the the following header:

```
My first chapter blah-blah            1
```

I want to get this:

```
Chapter 1: My first chapter blah-blah            1
```

What templates should I call to create such autotext?

Comment: Many people here are familiar with XSLT but not with Docbook. So you might want to answer the following questions. Where do you call the template "header.content"? Is the number of the chapter a parameter or does it have to be generated from scratch?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the following (trying because I am not too familiar with DocBook):

Add

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="object.title.markup"/>
```

to the `header.content` template. This should insert the "chapter title with chapter number label". See the Docbook documentation reference [here](http://sagehill.net/docbookxsl/PrintHeaders.html#PrintHeadersText).

```
<xsl:template name="header.content">
    <xsl:param name="pageclass" select="''"/>
    <xsl:param name="sequence" select="''"/>
    <xsl:param name="position" select="''"/>
    <xsl:param name="gentext-key" select="''"/>

  <fo:block>

    <!-- sequence can be odd, even, first, blank -->
    <!-- position can be left, center, right -->
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="$sequence = 'blank'">
        <!-- nothing -->
      </xsl:when>

      <xsl:when test="$position='left'">
        <xsl:call-template name="draft.text"/>
        <xsl:text>Chapter </xsl:text>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="object.title.markup"/>
        </xsl:text> </xsl:text>
        </xsl:when>
    </xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="$position='right'">
       <fo:page-number/>
     </xsl:when>
  </fo:block>
</xsl:template>
```

But note that there might be a difference between `title.markup` and `titleabbrev.markup`.